# Evento onchange não funciona no <select>

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos

O evento `change` não está funcionando. Não é possível alterar os valores resgatados dos elementos buscados:

```js
function trimestre(){
    var op = document.getElementById('tt').Value;
    if(op == 1){
        document.getElementById('vp').value = 18;
        document.getElementById('vt').value = 30;
    }else if(op == 2 || op == 3){
        document.getElementById('np').value = 21;
        document.getElementById('vt').value = 35;
    }
}
```

```html
<label>Trimestre: </label><select name="trimestre" id="tt" onchange="trimestre()">
  <option value="1">Primeiro</option>
  <option value="2">Segundo</option>
  <option value="3">Terceiro</option>
</select><br><br>
<label>Valor do trimestre: </label><input type="text" readonly id="vt" value="30"><br><br>
<label>Nota para passar: </label><input type="text" name="nota" id="np" readonly value="18"><br><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como é possível verificar na **segunda linha**, você está acessando a propriedade `Value`. O correto é `value`, já que o JavaScript difere letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Além disso, você está procurando um elemento com `id` `np`, que não existe:

> ```
> getElementById('vp')
> ```

O correto, no caso, seria:

```
getElementById('np')
```

Assim, ao corrigir os problemas, teremos:

```js
function trimestre(){
    var op = document.getElementById('tt').value;
    
    if (op == 1) {
        document.getElementById('np').value = 18;
        document.getElementById('vt').value = 30;
    } else if (op == 2 || op == 3) {
        document.getElementById('np').value = 21;
        document.getElementById('vt').value = 35;
    }
}
```

```html
<label>Trimestre:</label>
<select name="trimestre" id="tt" onchange="trimestre()">
  <option value="1">Primeiro</option>
  <option value="2">Segundo</option>
  <option value="3">Terceiro</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<label>Valor do trimestre:</label>
<input type="text" readonly id="vt" value="30">

<br><br>

<label>Nota para passar:</label>
<input type="text" name="nota" id="np" readonly value="18">
```

Comment: kkkkkkk não acredito que eu n vi esse V maiúsculo... puts velho, foram umas 2 horas só procurando esse maldito

Comment: mas eu acabo de testar e continua sem funcionar..... copiei teu código e substitui no meu, e ainda não funcionou, mas aqui no SO quando executo funciona

Comment: Editei a resposta. O outro problema estava no ID do elemento. ;)